How to unit test a QuerydslBinderCustomizer with Mockito in Spring Data JPA?
I'm trying to write a unit test for a QuerydslBinderCustomizer method in a Spring Data JPA repository. Here's the code I'm working with:
    @Override
    default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QGenericClass root) {
        bindings.bind(String.class)
                .first((SingleValueBinding<StringPath, String>) StringExpression::containsIgnoreCase);
    }

My goal is to test that the customize method correctly configures the binding for String fields with a containsIgnoreCase condition. I have written the following test using Mockito:
       @Test
        void testCustomize() {
                QuerydslBindings bindings = mock(QuerydslBindings.class);
                QGenericClass qGenericClass = mock(QGenericClass .class);

                genericClassRepository.customize(bindings, qGenericClass);

                ArgumentCaptor<SingleValueBinding> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(SingleValueBinding.class);
                verify(bindings).bind(eq(String.class), captor.capture());

                SingleValueBinding<StringPath, String> binding = captor.getValue();
                assertNotNull(binding);

                StringPath stringPath = mock(StringPath.class);
                when(stringPath.containsIgnoreCase(any())).thenReturn(mock(StringExpression.class));

                binding.bind(stringPath, () -> "testValue");
                verify(stringPath).containsIgnoreCase("testValue");
        }

Is there a better way to write this test, or am I missing something?

What is FQN of QGenericClass, StringPath and StringExpression?
